# Searching DataTable with string containing space c#

Tags: c#, datatable

So I've done a lot of searching for this one and can't figure it out.  I have a csv file that i'm writing off to a DataTable and populating a combo box from that same datatable.  The Idea is to search a user selected value in the data table and return the ID of that selection from the same data table.  The problem I'm having is that the selections all have spaces since they are capacity environments.  Is there a way to take the string and search the datatable column "Description" and return the column "ID"?  here is the code:

```
internal static void envRequest(string e)
    {
        DataRow[] foundRows;

         foundRows = variables.capEnvTable.Select(e);
        //variables.envID = foundRows[0].ToString();

        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows.ToString());
    }
}
```

The DataTable is formated as "ID" - "Name" - "Description"

The value of e is the user selected value such as "Buckeye Hosting Zone 2 Aries"

Right now I'm getting a System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Hosting' operator.'  on the 
    foundRows = variables.capEnvTable.Select(e);

Comment: 1. Thread.Sleep is bad 2. You say return column ID from the column description... how does a result from the datatable look?

Comment: It's throwing the exception before i get a return.  I have a datagridview added that I'm using for testing to display the DataTable contents and everything is showing there flawlessly.

Comment: you're not getting selected one you are setting it. Is that correct?

Comment: Id have to know what variables is too.

Comment: Yes the value from the dropdown is being sent to the method as "e" correctly.  I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the spaces in the string that's causing the issue.  When i look at the inner exception is just says null.  variables. is just a class that i'm using to store global variables in

Comment: I mean `foundRows = variables.capEnvTable.Select(e);` are you trying to select a row or get a value, because it looks like you're trying to do both

Comment: I'm trying to select a value from one column and return a result from another.  For example.  It's looking for the user selected value in the "Description" column and return the value from the same row in the "ID" column

Comment: the code right now seems to try to select a row in a datagridview

Comment: yes, I'm trying to select a row that matches the value of "e" in the description column and return the value in the same row of the "id" column.  There are no duplicates in the csv and never will be due to the type of data that's being stored in the data table

Comment: you cant assign a select statement to a variabele

Comment: ah ok.  Sorry I'm still a novice.  Any idea how I could do it?

Comment: Do you want to find multiple rows or just 1, as of now it gets 1. (my code)

Comment: All I need is 1 row since there are no duplicates in the data table

Comment: then I suggest you take a look at my answer, if you put this in your method and replace "ValueYouWantToSearch" with `e` (I suggest to name it search or something as `e` isn't very descriptive) it should work

Comment: That did exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets say the first column (index 0) is the value you want to search and the 2nd column (index 1) is the value you want.

```
DataRow dataRow;
dataRow = 
    myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .FirstOrDefault( row => row[0] == "ValueYouWantToSearch" );
var value = dataRow[1];
```